# System.InvalidOperationException: 'Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.'

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, charts

I have a chart in a VB.NET form and there is the error in the title on the line: `DBDA.Fill(DS, "chtRevenue")`

Is there anything I am missing or is this code incorrect?

I am new to coding and I have never used charts before.

The chart is supposed to pull the date from an access database.

This is all the code that is relevent to the question:

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Public Class frmSalesAndRevenue
    Private DB As New DBControl
    Dim DBDA As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    Private DBCmd As New OleDbCommand
    Private READ As OleDbDataReader
    Private DBCon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
                                         "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\NewHotel.mdb;")

    Private Function NotEmpty(text As String) As Boolean
        Return Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)
    End Function

    Private Sub frmSalesAndRevenue_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DBCon.Open()
        DBCmd = New OleDbCommand
        DBDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(DBCmd)
        DBDA.Fill(DS, "chtRevenue")
        DBCon.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
        'Clear old graph and plot new graph
        chtRevenue.ChartAreas.Clear()
        chtRevenue.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1")

        With chtRevenue.ChartAreas("ChartArea1")
            .AxisX.Title = "DateBooked"
            .AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Purple
            .AxisY.Title = "Revenue"
            .AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Purple
        End With

        Dim Series As Series = chtRevenue.Series("revenue received")
        chtRevenue.DataSource = DS.Tables("chtRevenue")

        'Clear series and add new series
        chtRevenue.Series.Clear()
        chtRevenue.Series.Add("revenue received")
        chtRevenue.Series("revenue received").Color = Color.Purple
        chtRevenue.Series("revenue received").ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column

        With chtRevenue
            .Series(0).XValueMember = "DateBooked"
            .Series(0).XValueMember = "Revenue"
        End With

        Dim x As DateTime
        Dim y As Int32

        chtRevenue.Series("revenue received").Points.Add(x.ToOADate(), y)
    End Sub
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @Steeeve Yes and it throws the error ```System.InvalidOperationException: 'Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.'``` on the line: ```DBDA.Fill(DS, "chtRevenue")```

Comment: Thats because in your `LoadChart` method you don't specify how to read the data from your database. `DBCmd` does not have a CommandText specified. It is also unclear what your variable `DS` is. You should post more code.

Comment: @Steeeve Sorry, I forgot about that part

Comment: Well, if this is all the code, you can't fill the DataSet `DS` without telling the DataAdapter how to read the data from the database. I would suggest to have a look at [ADO.NET code examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples#oledb). As soon as your dataset is filled with the right data, you can get to step two regarding charts (if you then still have problems).

Comment: @Steeeve Thank you, I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function NotEmpty(text As String) As Boolean
    Return Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)
End Function
```

This function doesn't seem to have much purpose. Just use the `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` method directly in your code.

Don't declare connections outside of the method where they are used. `Connection`s and `DataAdapter`s need to be disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks are provided for this purpose. The constructor of the `DataAdapter` can take the `CommandText` and the connection. The `DataAdapter` will open and close the connection as part of the `Fill` method.

```
Dim DS As New DataSet
Private MyConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\NewHotel.mdb;"

Private Sub frmSalesAndRevenue_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Using DBCon As New OleDbConnection(MyConStr),
            DBDA As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select SomeFields From SomeTable", DBCon)
        DBDA.Fill(DS, "chtRevenue")
    End Using
End Sub
```